# Add css before appending child

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild

So I have a div (with the id of "thecolor2") that I want to append to an unordered list, but before I append it, I want to set its background color to a variable which has the value of a hex code. However, for some reason, it doesn't take in the color.

Here is the CSS:

```
#thecolor2{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 635px;
}
```

Her is the HTML:

```
<ul id = "allposts"></ul>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var thestream = document.getElementById('allposts');
var oneofpost = document.createElement('li');
var thecolor2 = document.createElement('div');
thecolor2.id = "thecolor2";
$("#thecolor2").css("background-color", color);
thestream.appendChild(oneofpost);
thestream.appendChild(thecolor2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use a jQuery ID selector to match a node which hasn't been added to the document tree. You can simply use plain DOM to set its inline CSS style like this:

```
thecolor2.style.backgroundColor = color
```

Comment: Yeah, the main issue is that he is trying to select (via `$('#thecolor2')`) from the DOM an element that is not there yet. As a side note, though, you can use the plain JS element as the argument of the jQuery `$` function and it will work without having to add that element to the DOM, like: `$(thecolor2).css("background-color", color)`.

Comment: @acdcjunior You are perfectly right, but I thought: that's the only line in which jQuery is used, why don't use plain DOM there too? Plus, I don't like jQuery too much, so...

Comment: I agree, Carlo, you addressed the main points in your answer, and using plain JS there is better.

Answer (score 2):

As described by Carlo in another answer, you cannot use the jQuery selector to select elements that haven't been added. You can however, turn a created DOM element into a jQuery object by doing:

```
var thecolor2 = $(document.createElement('div'));
```

However, if you're going to be using jQuery then I suggest writing everything in jQuery, otherwise stick with using pure JavaScript for everything.

### jQuery

```
var thestream = $('#allposts');
var oneofpost = $('<li></li>');
var thecolor2 = $('<div></div>');
thecolor2.prop('id', "thecolor2")
         .css({
             backgroundColor: color
         }).appendTo(oneofpost);
thestream.append(oneofpost);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPk4M/1/)

### JavaScript

```
var thestream = document.getElementById('allposts');
var oneofpost = document.createElement('li');
var thecolor2 = document.createElement('div');
thecolor2.id = "thecolor2";
thecolor2.style.backgroundColor = color;
oneofpost.appendChild(thecolor2);
thestream.appendChild(oneofpost);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPk4M/)

Also I'm assuming you're trying to append a list item to the `ul`, so I corrected the code you had there with `appendChild`.